# Mac OS X Homestead - edit php.ini

Tags: php, macos, nginx, homestead

I have Homestead installed on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6). I need to enable short tags via my php.ini file. All the posts I've read say to go to a path like /etc/php/7.0/... but I don't have that php folder in etc/ . I can see the files /etc/php.ini.default and /etc/php.ini.default-5.2-previous. In the /etc/php.ini.default the short tag config looks like this:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

I can edit (via sudo) to read like this

```
short_open_tag = On
```

But not sure if that did the job, as I don't know if I need to (or how to) restart php or nginx...?

Comment: did you install php yourself or are you riding with the OSX distributed php?

Comment: ps : any line that starts with `;` is a comment, you are basically editing the documentation :)  ... insert a line like this : `short_open_tag     On`

Comment: I haven't installed php exclusively, but I think it's installed as part of the Homestead stack, e.g PHP 7.0 is listed as included software in the installation guide I followed here: https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead

Comment: haha, thanks @YvesLeBorg - I've changed the actual setting now (and updated the question), but short tags are still not working. DO I need to restart php/nginx? Not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php-fpm, you need to restart that !

I dont know your stack, so have no practical advice to offer. However, to make certain you are editing the right .ini, however, on the box running php, issue the following :

```
php -r "echo phpinfo();" | grep "\.ini"
```

which will list the ini files loaded, and their location(s). That is the one you need to edit. The output looks like this on my box :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-libevent.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-propro.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-raphf.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/zzz_ext-http.ini
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
```

Comment: Thanks. When I ran it, it just listed the etc/ directory (no php.ini file), so I duplicated the php.ini.default file and renamed it php.ini. I then ran the phpinfo() command again and now it says...
  
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini

...but short tags still not working?

BTW I'm using the Homestead Vagrant Box, the stack is listed here  laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead